# How to refire a data event in qooxdoo?

Tags: events, qooxdoo

fire a event from qooxdoo, how should I do?

ClassA dispatches the event A of type MyEvent and ClassB listens for that event. Then classB dispatches the same event B of type MyEvent with the same data..
In classB I've made this:

```
        var target = evt.getTarget();
        this.fireEvent("A", MyEvent, [target])
```

but I'm repeating code, it's possible to do it more automated?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could enclose this logic inside a qooxdoo global variable and then just call the variable as a function:

```
var standardEvent : function() {
    var target = evt.getTarget();
    this.fireEvent("A", MyEvent, [target])
}
```

and the call it in your subclasses:

```
qx.core.Init.getApplication().standardEvent();
```

You'd have to figure out the scope, though.

Comment: I think doing some bubbling like qooxdoo does in it's UI components might be good, but I didn't yet looked into that matter... What do you think?